# NullReferenceexception using glimpse

Tags: asp.net, glimpse

I found the following exception in my error log:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at Glimpse.AspNet.RequestMetadata.get_ClientId()
at Glimpse.Core.Framework.GlimpseRequest..ctor(Guid requestId, IRequestMetadata   
   requestMetadata,  IDictionary`2 tabData, IDictionary`2 displayData, TimeSpan duration)
at Glimpse.Core.Framework.GlimpseRuntime.EndRequest()
at Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule.EndRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext)
at Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule.<Init>b__3(Object context, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.
       System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I'm running glimpse core v1.6, the following config:
    •Registered Tabs:
    ◦Other ◾Elmah - Glimpse.Elmah.Plugin

```
◦Glimpse.Ado (1.5.0)◾SQL - Glimpse.Ado.Tab.SQL

◦Glimpse.AspNet (1.4.0)◾Configuration - Glimpse.AspNet.Tab.Configuration
◾Environment - Glimpse.AspNet.Tab.Environment
◾Request - Glimpse.AspNet.Tab.Request
◾Routes - Glimpse.AspNet.Tab.Routes
◾Server - Glimpse.AspNet.Tab.Server
◾Session - Glimpse.AspNet.Tab.Session

◦Glimpse (1.6.0)◾Timeline - Glimpse.Core.Tab.Timeline
◾Trace - Glimpse.Core.Tab.Trace

 Want to create your own Tabs - see here!
•Runtime Policies: ◦Glimpse (1.6.0)◾Glimpse.Core.Policy.AjaxPolicy 
◾Glimpse.Core.Policy.ContentTypePolicy 
◾Glimpse.Core.Policy.ControlCookiePolicy 
◾Glimpse.Core.Policy.GlimpseResourcePolicy 
◾Glimpse.Core.Policy.StatusCodePolicy 
◾Glimpse.Core.Policy.UriPolicy
```

EDIT:
Some more info:

This is running on an Azure web site. While the uncaught exception gets logged (by Elmah), I don't think an error page every makes it's way to the end user.

Comment: Do you have a question? If this is a bug report it should be submitted to [the Glimpse issue tracker](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues).

Comment: I don't know if it's a bug or a configuration issue.

Comment: Is this in production, test or on your dev box?

Comment: It's in production on an Azure web site. Based on the IP address in the log, it's actually my browsing that caused the error, more than likely with the glimpse cookie enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem.

After various checks, the problem was resolved by resetting Visual Studio settings.

Tools > Import and Export Settings

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue today. Turns out it simply that I needed to update the Glimpse NuGet packages as I was using versions that were no longer supported by the newer MVC / ASP.NET technology.

After this, I got a runtime error relating to the System.Web.Mvc.Html reference in my Web.Config. This was subsequently fixed by Cleaning my solution then changing the "Copy Local" property against the System.Web.Mvc reference to True.